# What namespace includes the type HolograhicFrameData?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, mrtk

I'm using this Microsoft Documentation to work with Spatial meshes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/scene-understanding-sdk

Under the "Dealing with Transforms" section, they have this example code :

```
private System.Numerics.Matrix4x4? GetSceneToUnityTransformAsMatrix4x4(SceneUnderstanding.Scene scene)


  System.Numerics.Matrix4x4? sceneToUnityTransform = System.Numerics.Matrix4x4.Identity;

  Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem sceneCoordinateSystem = Microsoft.Windows.Perception.Spatial.Preview.SpatialGraphInteropPreview.CreateCoordinateSystemForNode(scene.OriginSpatialGraphNodeId);
  HolograhicFrameData holoFrameData =  Marshal.PtrToStructure<HolograhicFrameData>(UnityEngine.XR.XRDevice.GetNativePtr());
  Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem unityCoordinateSystem = Microsoft.Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem.FromNativePtr(holoFrameData.ISpatialCoordinateSystemPtr);

  sceneToUnityTransform = sceneCoordinateSystem.TryGetTransformTo(unityCoordinateSystem);

  if(sceneToUnityTransform != null)
  {
      sceneToUnityTransform = ConvertRightHandedMatrix4x4ToLeftHanded(sceneToUnityTransform.Value);
  }
  else
  {
      return null;
  }

return sceneToUnityTransform;
```

I am unable to use the HolograhicFrameData datatype, as it cannot be found. I have searched through all of the documentation, but it explicitly says at the top : "All of the types described below reside in the Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding namespace". Searching for this type on Google only leads to the documentation I previously mentioned. I also tried using Microsoft.Windows.Graphics.Holographic; But to no avail.

What namespace includes the type HolograhicFrameData?

Comment: Just did, deleted the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the name and is probably a custom class. A little mistake, the closest class I found was [HolographicFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.holographic.holographicframe?view=winrt-19041).

The variable `holoFrameData` instance of `HolographicFrameData` class uses `ISpatialCoordinateSystemPtr` property, which is inherited by `IWindowsMixedRealityUtilitiesProvider` interface

Found another reference, but not the same [HolographicFrameNativeData](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.WindowsMixedReality.HolographicFrameNativeData.html)

It's used here as well [Mixed Reality (Unity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-xrdevice-advanced)